# Can I restart Cassandra without restarting Spark worker?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

Is there a way to restart Cassandra without restarting Spark worker in Datastax Enterprise (DSE)?

Comment: Currently this is not possible, what is your use case?

Comment: I have a long-running Spark job/application. `service dse restart` will not make the Spark worker join the job.

Comment: Hmm, well that's kind of a different question than your original. "New Workers can be added
at any point." per the mailing list - http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201404.mbox/%3CCANGvG8p=-r1VZcQ9mMGnoO1EMmCea4-BSZTT7bxu6JRieyBx9w@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to user Phact in the comment:

> Currently this is not possible [...]